# Hide button if radio button is checked on load

Tags: jquery

"No" is set as the default, I want to hide the submit button if No is selected. On the next page, the submit button uses the same class, i do not want it hidden.

```
<label>yes, I do agree</label><input type="radio" value="yes, I do agree">
<label>no, I do not agree</label><input type="radio" value="no, I do not agree">

<div class="submit">submit</div>
```

The problem I am having is if No is set to the default then the submit button is not hidden on load only if I choose Yes then choose No again. If I tell it to hide the submit button on load then on the next step the submit button will be hidden.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Normally it's the best way to show what you've tried so far to solve this problem.

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this to achieve what you desire:

```
$(".submit").hide();
$("input").click(function() {
    $(".submit").hide();
    if($("input[value=yes]:checked").length) {
        $(".submit").show();
    }
});
```

jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/kingcodefish/sza8Lb92/

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  if ( $('[value^=no]').is(':checked') ) {
    $('.submit').hide();
  }
});
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/derekmx271/0e145hLm/)

Comment: Lol why the downvote, this works just fine. To unhide the submit button, just write a simple conditional to `.show()` it!

Answer (score 0):

Add an id to the no button (and also recommend id to the submit button). Then:

```
$(document).ready(function(){       
    if ($('[id of no button]').is(':checked')) $('.submit').hide();
}
```

Comment: I cannot touch the HTML, it is automatically generated by the software. I would have to write a script to add the id as well.

Comment: the replace that part with `$('input[value="no, I do not agree"]')`. The problem with these things is that if you have another element with the same value or another element belonging to the `submit` class, the code will not work properly.